# Showing only one space instead of more than one spaces in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing a problem of the spacing in a table values.

I have a simple table with a header `Item Title` and I am showing its value in it,
but for the value 'Salil     Gaikwad' it is just showing `Salil Gaikwad`.

It means it is simply showing one space for more than one spaces when I retrieve 
it as `<%= @item.item_title %>` but I want to show it the same way as it is saved in the database
i.e. Salil + 5 spaces + Gaikwad

Answer (score 6):

You could use the html tag **pre** around your text in the cell to preserve the spaces. Otherwise you can substitute the spaces with the html char **&nbsp** with something like this:

```
@item.item_title.gsub(/\s/, "&nbsp;")
```

Comment: To explain a little but further... in HTML, any sequence of whitespace characters represents a single space to be rendered.  It doesn't matter how many spaces you send to the browser, it will normally display just one.  This has nothing to do with Rails in particular.

Comment: Thanx it works .........but i get surprised if rails don't have any method to do the same.

Comment: I don't think there is a method for that. Never saw it. you're welcome Salil.

Comment: THis method is not necessary as far as it is useless :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an html thing.

Try to wrap the result in pre tags (

```
<%= ... %>
```

)

Or you can use the css white-space: property, using the needed selector.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use the css white-space property on your html table. Since you want to preserve the white space, you can use the pre, pre-wrap, pre-line values as need.

See this link for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

```
table { white-space: <one of pre, pre-wrap, pre-line>; }
```